# Docker - modifying IPTABLES for host from container

Tags: docker, iptables, fail2ban

I want to run a docker container with central log and `fail2ban` service to prevent from dos/ddos attacks.

I'm having a problem to run a container with such capabilities that it could also modify the hosts iptables.

There is a project [ianblenke/docker-fail2ban](https://github.com/ianblenke/docker-fail2ban) however it does not work...

Giving the container flag privileged only allows me to control `iptables` on this container. Is there any way to control hosts `iptables` through container?

Regards.

Comment: Why would you want to run fail2ban inside a container ?

Comment: I'm running multiply services on different containers and I would like to have a central container which will be responsible for preventing dos/ddos attacks...

Comment: I'm exploring a teaching activity that uses iptables to partition containerised mongodb replicasets and similarly need to poke host vm iptables from inside a container. How do I do that (ie what commands in container allow the container to manipulate the host vm iptables?)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Docker containers, by default, run inside an isolated network namespace where they do not have access to the host network configuration (including iptables).

If you want your container to be able to modify the network configuration of the host, you need to pass the `--net=host` option to `docker run`.   From the `docker-run(1)` man page:

```
--net="bridge"
   Set the Network mode for the container
       'bridge': creates a new network stack for the container on the docker bridge
       'none': no networking for this container
       'container:': reuses another container network stack
       'host':  use  the host network stack inside the container.
       Note: the host mode gives the container full access to
       local system services such as D-bus and is therefore
       considered insecure.
```

You will need to run with both `--privileged` and `--net=host`.

Comment: it worked I thought I was testing this, but I was using net="bridge" - it worked - thx.

Comment: Maciej, can you please tell how you got to the host's iptables from the container?

Comment: Does it make sense, though? `dockerd` itself curates its own rules in the host's iptables. If you run anything that manipulates firewall rules, you risk messing up with the rules placed by `dockerd`. If anything, you need to be absolutely sure what that tool is doing to your iptables before letting it lose with `--privileged --net=host`.

Answer (score 17):

`--privileged` flag is not required anymore. 
Starting with Docker 1.2 you can now run your image with parameters `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` and `--cap-add=NET_RAW` which will allow internal iptables.

It might be also worth noticing that in official Ubuntu images from Docker Hub `iptables` package is not installed.
So general instruction should be

- `apt-get install iptables`
- run docker container with `--net=host` and `--cap-add=NET_ADMIN` `--cap-add=NET_RAW` options.

Also, if you have a docker image that is missing `iptables` package, and you don't want to create a custom image from it, you may run container with `iptables` in the same network space. E.g. if you have container `container-without-iptables` running, and you want to start some `container-with-iptables` in the same network namespace, you can do:

```
docker run -it --pid=container:container-without-iptables --net=container:container-without-iptables --cap-add sys_admin container-with-iptables
```