# run fail2ban in kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, fail2ban

My Situation at the moment:
I'm setting up a mail server and just after getting it to work, the logs are flooded with `authentication failed` messages from an suspicious iran network trying to login to random accounts.

After some googeling I found out that `fail2ban` can stop those attacks, but there's one problem: how to use fail2ban in kubernetes?
My Ideas:

- I found [this plugin](https://pilot.traefik.io/plugins/280093067746214409/fail2-ban) for traefik, but it requres the traefik instance to be connected to thei SaaS managment service, what I don't need
- Installing `fail2ban` on the host: As kubernetes connects multiole nodes, `fail2ban` on node 1 only gets the logs from this node and cannot block traffik coming in on node 2.

Is there a solution to run fail2ban In kubernetes, maybe linked to the ingress controller, as it is possible with  traefik, but without any connection to a SaaS provider?

Comment: Did you come up with a way that works for you?

Comment: I'm working on it: https://gitlab.com/Hobyte/kube2fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In theory, you will need to run `fail2ban` with certain capabilities:

```
  "spec": {
    "hostNetwork": true,
    "containers": [{
      "name": "netadmin",
      "securityContext": {"capabilities": { "add": ["NET_ADMIN", "NET_RAW"] }}
```

See here:

[Docker - modifying IPTABLES for host from container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30169013/docker-modifying-iptables-for-host-from-container)

and here:

[relationship between K8S iptables and the one of a container inside a pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230369/relationship-between-k8s-iptables-and-the-one-of-a-container-inside-a-pod)

You will also need to pass the correct logs to `fail2ban` inside the container.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really a good way to do this. Both on the log access front, and more importantly on tweaking the iptables rules from inside a container. You could definitely use the core engine of fail2ban to build a tool around the k8s native APIs (`pods/logs`, NetworkPolicy) however I don't know any such project at time of writing.

Comment: Getting the logs can be achieved using [kail](https://github.com/boz/kail)